# How to show only issues from current sprint on a YouTrack board?

Tags: youtrack, sprint

Currently, the board is set up with "Link sprints to values for Fix versions" behavior
 (where "Fix versions" is a custom field):
[image]

The query is currently fetching `Fix versions: {IMS 3.13-02}`, but I want it to be generic and not hardcoded to this particular sprint, e.g. something like `Fix versions: current sprint`.
It's needed so that issues that were assigned to this sprint are visible there and when board is switched to next sprint (e.g. `{IMS 3.13-03}`) that the query automatically shows only issues for that sprint (as they will have that "Sprint Name" set via "Fix versions").

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Hello, this is actually not a query. Linking sprints to a "Fix versions" custom field leads to the following: all issues with Fix Versions set to some value will appear on the corresponding sprint (which name matches this value). Current sprint is just a sprint which starts before the current date and ends after that. Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Sprint-Options.html#link-sprints-new and clarify your scenario if I got you wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ana Bartasheva comment, the solution is just removing the `Fix versions: {IMS 3.13-02}` from the "Link sprints to values for Fix versions" query. It was superfluos b/c they (sprint and fix versions) were already linked.